# Why does the anonymous callback work but the named callback fail?

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, phaser-framework

I have the following code:

```
this.leaves.forEach(this.leafFloat(leaf));

private leafFloat(leaf: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite): () => void {
    return function() { 

        leaf.setVelocityX(-50);
    }
}
```

But I get the error "Cannot find name 'leaf'".

If I make the callback an anonymous function like so:

```
this.leaves.forEach((leaf) => { leaf.setVelocityX(-50)});
```

It runs exactly as expected, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the first line you pass as a parameter the variable `leaf`, which is not defined previously.

```js
this.leaves.forEach(this.leafFloat(leaf));
//                                  ^- here
```

However, in the lambda function, you are calling the parameter `leaf`, which is correctly defined.

```js
this.leaves.forEach((leaf) => { leaf.setVelocityX(-50)});
//                    ^-defined   ^-called
```

Comment: Which as far as i understand it should be directly
`this.leaves.forEach(this.leafFloat);`
and it's executing this function on every children for that leaves container

Comment: What is the proper way to pass in the value of the item from an array that `foreach` is iterating through? The documentation makes it look like this is how you would do it?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_foreach.htm

Comment: I think that it depends. If you are going to reuse the function of the forEach loop in another point of your code, the first approach keeps your code DRY, as it won't be repeated. If it's just used in that moment, then I would prefer the anonymous/lambda function, because your code will be cleaner that way. I think your case is the second, so I would stick with the lambda.